# ClassNotFoundException for org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook

Tags: tomcat, grails, apache-poi

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for

> org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook

which is contained in

> poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar

that I have on my classpath.

Compile and deploy are running fine, but on runtime I get that exception above. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try having org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.10-FINAL jar in your classpath? This schema jar contains the files starting with 'CT'

Answer (score 1):

You are missing at least one [dependency of Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). As detailed on the [components and dependencies page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), the POI OOXML code such as XSSF depends on either poi-ooxml-schemas (small) or ooxml-schemas (big)

Add the appropriate one to your classpath (they both come in the binary jar), and it'll work. Well, assuming you also included the other [dependencies listed](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) too!